# What kind of controller naming format Sylius use in yaml config files?

Tags: sylius

f.e. lets compare two routing yaml files:

[ShopBundle/Resources/config/routing/product.yml](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/config/routing/product.yml)

[ShopBundle/Resources/config/routing/taxon.yml](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/config/routing/taxon.yml)

both have _controller atribute:

```
_controller: sylius.controller.product:showAction
```

and

```
_controller: sylius.controller.taxon:showAction
```

and both match same controller:
ResourceBundle/Controller/ResourceController.php#L167

- What kind of controller naming format Sylius use in yaml config files? Why it not looks like `Bundle:Controller:action` ?
- How to find this controller other than hunting it in the project code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius uses controllers as services (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html). To easily find the related code to that service I suggest you to install the Symfony2 plugin for PHPStorm, you can find it here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=idea.

The plugin uses the build container in your cache folder. So you should make sure that symfony has properly build your definitions once. So try running `php app/console cache:clear` or simply run your application.

You should use `Ctrl + click` or `Cmd + click` on for example service id's, Twig template names etc.